# How to change position of UIButton?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

Nothing happens but why ???

```
@IBOutlet weak var button10: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button10.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.x/2, y: self.view.frame.y/2)

 }
```

Comment: do you want to put the button in center of view?

Comment: yes but i does not move

Comment: you are using autolayout?

Comment: yes do i have to change this ?

Comment: You should be using autolayout, and when using auto layout, you shouldn't be setting positions/sizes manually like this.  If you *are* using auto layout, you should specify that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Add constraints for center in view

```
var constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button10, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(constX)

var constY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button10, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(constY)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ashhish said, add two constraints between the parent view and the button. But this can also be done using the awesome Github project [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography):

```
layout(view, button) {
    parent, button in
    button.centerX == parent.centerX
    button.centerY == parent.centerY
}
```

Very neat!

You can include Cartography using [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/).